# Using Delete in Perl

Tags: perl, reference

I'm creating a graph data structure that contains essentially an array of nodes (and edgeList with extra information).  I also have a hash that allows me to quickly get a reference to a particular node by giving its name.  Suppose I now want to implement a removeNode() function in the graph class, how can I delete something quickly.  Let's say the function takes the name of a node, and I hash directly to it (and have a reference to that node).  Delete takes arrays or hashes as a parameter, but within an array I want to delete the object that I have a reference to.

Any ideas?

Comment: Is there any reason why you are not using the excellent Graph module? http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Graph

Answer (score 1):

I'm not clear on exactly what you're trying to do. If you just want to remove an item from a hash, `delete $hash{$key};` is all you need.

If you want to remove an item from an array, and not leave that index undefined, then you can use `splice @array, $index, 1;` which will remove the item and shift everything after it down one spot.

If you want to just remove an element from an array but leave the rest of the list alone, then you can just undefine it: `$array[$index] = undef;`

That's the same thing that `delete $array[$index]` does, but using `delete` on an array index is deprecated.

**Edit**:

If you need to *find* an object in an array and then delete it, the best way is to use [`firstidx`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?List%3a%3aMoreUtils) from List::MoreUtils, e.g.

```
use List::MoreUtils 'firstidx';

my $obj = get_object_to_delete();
my $index = firstidx { $_ eq $obj } @array;
splice @array, $index, 1;
```

This assumes the objects stringify to something suitable for comparing for equality. If they have stringification overloaded, use something like [`refaddr`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Scalar%3a%3aUtil) from Scalar::Util to get the numeric reference address directly.

Comment: @friedo Essentially my question is this.  I have an array and a reference to a particular object in it, but not necessarily a number of its index.  Does delete $array[$reference] work just as if I had the index as a number?

Comment: No.  Keep the index in another hash which has the key value as its name.  That way you can undef the array entry and delete from both hashes.  Do not splice the array element away; that will cause all those indexes you saved to not point to the correct entry.

Comment: @friedo None of my hashes actually keep indices as their values.  A better way to rephrase this would be:  I want to splice() out a value from an array having only a reference to the object I want to delete and not its index.  Indices are never saved in a hash, only references to objects.  I never want to directly refer to a part of the array via an index anywhere in the code.

Comment: @arjun, if you want to splice something out of the array, you have to know the index. Either you need to keep track of it ahead of time, or search for it when you need it.

Comment: or, as the deleted answer shows, reassign all other elements of the array like `@a = grep { notTheObjectYoureLookingFor($_) } @a;`

Comment: Good point, ysth, though I think rebuilding the entire array each time is probably not the optimal solution. :)